# Samba: Give each user his own folder

Tags: samba

how do you configure the smb.conf file, so that each user added to the Samba database has it's own folder, which is not his home folder?

Say I have a folder placed in root, called Samba. Within that Samba folder I want to have a folder for each user. That user will only see his folder, when he logs into the server. However, there has to be a super user who will see the whole folder structure.

How would I accomplish that within the smb.conf file? I couldn't find any good resources on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the users share create a share with the `%U` in the path (e.g. `path = /srv/folder/%U`).  Then simply create a separate share setup so only the administrator can access it that points at the parent folder.

See the `VARIABLE SUBSTITUTIONS` section in the [smb.conf man pages](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html).

Comment: I'm not quite sure, if this is exactly the thing I want.

I just can't seem to get it.
My smb.conf file hast a section as follow:

`[share]
comment = share folder
path = /home/samba/share
read only = no
valid user = me
write list = me
read list = me
`
Still it shows me the folder, but I'm not allowed to do anything.

Comment: Ok... just for the record. The problem was with the permissions. I added the directories using root, therefore couldn't access them using another user. chown -Rv username userdir helped. Thanks for your help though.